# Install-Package on MacOS

Tags: macos, botframework

I'm trying to use a Cosmos DB with C# as documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#using-cosmos-db.

But I can't figure out how to `Install-Package Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure` since I don't have PowerShell. Couldn't do it with the `az` command. Do I need to install PowerShell (apparently another >200MB) just for this?

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to just [install the package via NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio). Alternatively, you can [install PowerShell on MacOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-macos?view=powershell-7) and then run that command within PowerShell